# Does "Supress Map in # Turns" mean sealing monster portals

Tags: kamidori-alchemy-meister

In Chapter 6 of the Serawi Route "Herald of the Dark" in the map where you have to servery the area for the new waterway by going to all the mining points one of the bonus clear objectives is to "Suppress Map in 9 turns" (am able to tell as i am using New Game + data with the option to see all bonus clear objectives set to on) however i'm not sure if it's just the monster portals i need to seal or if i need to kill every monster on the map

i would do it myself however the strategy is different depending on which it is, if i just have to seal portals then i can create a bunch of seal stones and seal them up at a distance however i need materials for that which i don't want to waist as they are also used for enhancing Serawi's, Emilita's and Yeula's armors, if i need to wipe out all monsters then i'll need to be on a higher level for most of my Mana girls (Suina, Aht, Sharty, Lilly) so i can one shot most of the monsters and have Kohakuren and the Reaper whatever her name is (it's like Rigu-something) because they both have the Interdimension ability which would allow them to warp past the map barriers into other rooms but i don't get them till Chapter 7 or 8

Either method will take time to get ready so i am wondering if "Suppress Map in 9 turns" means to just seal up all the monster portals or if i need to wipe out every monster, that way i can prepare while i'm doing all the other quests i have piled up which most need to be finished before Chapter 7

Comment: "kamidori-alchemy-mIEster"... I haven't felt so offended by a spelling mistake in a long time. If anyone can rename the tag itself (not just edit its wiki), please make it say "meister" instead of "miester".

Comment: As for the question itself, I haven't played Kamidori in ages, but if my memory serves me right, map suppression should stand for both portals and monsters alike. Take it with a grain of salt, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [translators wiki:](http://kamidori.seiha.org/index.php?title=Locations)
The game makes a distinction between suppress the map and suppress the portals.

Suppress the map means 100 percent clear the map, which requires destroying all monsters and closing all portals.

Suppress the portals means close all portals.

Unfortunately my current save is not high enough to double-check the 100 percenting the map issue.

Comment: @nolonar You realize that exact link is present in my answer, right? The wiki just doesn't mention it from what I saw. Edit: actually it does answer it on a second look

Comment: Oops, I failed to notice the link. Sorry and nevermind my comment then.